# Sum function is not iterable

Tags: python

```
score = {
  'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4,
  'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 10, 'l': 1,
  'm': 2, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 8, 'r': 1,
  's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 10, 'x': 10,
  'y': 10, 'z': 10,
}

x = input('Enter a Word: ')
y = list(x)
a = []
for i in x:
  z = int(score[i])
  a = sum(z)

  print(a)
```

`a= sum(z)` is keep on saying it is "int' object is not iterable".

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please see what you are getting using `print z` that is iterable value, for example if you first value it will print 'a' :1 so that you have to parse it again to get 1 value from the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you want `a` to store the sum of the letters in the word. If so, what you are doing is wrong. `sum()` function expects an iterable, and then it takes the sum by adding each element of that iterable and returns the sum. Example -

```
>>> sum([1,2,3,4])
10
```

It does not work like you are expecting it to.

In your case , you do not even need to use sum, simply do -

```
a = 0   #before the loop
```

and

```
a += z #inside the loop
```

And also you should indent the `print a` outisde the for loop, so that you only print the final sum of letters.

Comment: Alternately, `a = sum(score[c] for c in x)` for a nice and compact way to say the same thing. (But it might be a bit advanced for now.)

Comment: Yea, but I am guessing the OP is still learning so I would rather not tell them about generator expressions yet.

Comment: @Amadan the more compact would be `sum(score.values())` or `sum(score.itervalues())` depending on the python version.

Comment: @bereal: That does not do the same thing. I (and OP, and Anand S Kumar) do not sum `score` values, we sum `score` values corresponding to each character in `x`. If I need a spoon, a needle is not an acceptable more compact alternative. :)

Comment: @Amadan sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

As said @Amadan in the comments of @AnandSKumar answer, you could do the following :

```
a = sum(score[c] for c in x)
```

Supposing you are still learning Python, here is a explication of what does the above code.

First as explained @AnandSKumar, the `sum` built-in function takes as parameter an iterable. What is an iterable ? It's an object that implement the `__iter__` method which allows to iterate over the data of the object. The best example is a `list` object. Considere the following code :

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
try:
    while True:
        print next(my_list)
except StopIteration:
    print "The end."

# Result :
a
b
c
The end.
```

We iterate over the list `my_list`. The `sum` function could/would looks like this in Python implementation :

```
def sum(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    result = next(iterator, 0)
    try:
        while True:
            result += next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return result
```

A good approche of what you are doing could be to create a list as following, and the sum it :

```
a = [score[c] for c in x]
print sum(a)

# Equivalent code (one liner) :
print sum([score[c] for c in x])

# Equivalent code :
a = []
for c in x:
    a.append(c)

print sum(a)
```

The thing is that you generate entirely your list `a` and it takes memory. The approche of what @Amadan said is to generate dynamically the list `a` using a [generator expression](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html). The idea is to create an iterable, which has no representation in memory.

```
print sum(score[c] for c in x)

# Equivalent code :
result = 0
for c in x:
    result += score[c]
print result
```

This is more memory efficient and looks like you're a god of Python :)

The one-liner of what you are trying to do :

```
# Python 3
print sum(score[c] for c in input("Enter a word: "))

# Python 2
print sum(score[c] for c in raw_input("Enter a word: "))
```

Comment: A small point - `The sum function could/would looks like this in Python implementation :` needs a small correction. you would first need to call `iter(iterable)` . Try doing `next(list)` , you will see why.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your review, I edited the function. I also define the default value in case of empty iterator (`sum([]) == 0`).